# exporting and indexing csv file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I've created a csv file with the column names and saved it using pandas library. This file will be used to create a historic record where the rows will be charged one by one in different moments... what I'm doing to add rows to this csv previously created is transform the record to a DataFrame and then using to_csv() I choose mode = 'a' as a parameter in order to append this record to the existing file. The problem here is that I would like to see and index automatically generated in the file everytime I add a new row. I already know when I import this file as a DF, an index is generated automatically, but this is within the idle interface...when I open the csv with Excel for example...the file doesn't have an index.

Answer (score 1):

While writing your files to csv, you can use set `index = True` in the to_csv method. This ensures that the index of your dataframe is written explicitly to the csv file